# How to tag/mark an object in Ai file and keep it in a pdf format?

Tags: pdf, tags, adobe-illustrator

I have AI file and I tagged some of the arts using AITagSuite

(Tags are actually stored as string entries in the art object dictionary)

I want to convert the ai file to pdf without loosing the tags. when I convent the ai file to pdf I can't access the tags.

Any idea how to tag/mark an object in Ai file and keep it in a pdf?

I also thought about using some other libraries that can get AI file as an input and convert it to pdf with the tags, any idea?

Thank you in advanced

Comment: I don't know about other libraries but Illustrator still has no such feature, as far as I can tell. Hope it will added someday. Perhaps there is a two-steps workaround with Acrobat scripting. You can make a txt file from Illustrator with description of the objects (based on colors, sizes, for example, etc) and then to feed the txt file to the Acrobat script that will search for the objects in the PDF file and add the tags.

Comment: Thank you Yuri. 

Can you please guide me how to create the txt file from AI and how to feed the Acrobat script? where can I read about it?
thank you again

Comment: By 'txt file' I mean some list. You can iterate through all objects in your AI file, iterate through all tags of every object and make a list of objects ([position, color, tag], [position, color, tag], [position, color, tag] -- for example) and save the list on disk in a txt file (or JSON). This part is pretty simple. I can show you how it can be done if you post a sample of your AI file. But the next part -- to read the list by Acrobat and to search for objects with given properties in the PDF file is beyond my current expertise. I can't help you on this mater.

Comment: Thank you Yuri. About the second step, do you think it's possible to identify the object by  [position, color, tag] ?   what if I have several layers in the AI job?

Comment: I think it depends on what your AI looks like. But in most cases the four digits of the array `geometricBounds()` ([y1, x1, y2, x2] coordinates, I'm sure Acrobat has something alike) + color (one [Gray], three [RGB] or four [CMYK] digits) makes it very possible to identify an object. It doesn't matter which layer the object belongs to. The only possible error could be if you have several objects of the same size and color in the same position. I'm not ready to dive into murk waters of Acrobat scripting right now. I can try to write the Illustrator part of the task if you want.

Comment: Thank you Yuri.  I'll be glad if you cay try to write the Illustrator part of the task

Comment: I'll be glad too, I like to code. ) But I'll be busy for couple next days though. Stay tuned.

Comment: And I have no idea about the `AITagSuite`. And what exactly you're expecting to get in the PDF. Probably there can be a workaround. Say you can extract the tags and put them under your graphic on hidden layer and export the PDF with layers. This way you will have the 'tags' (as a plain text) in the PDF.

Comment: Thank you Yuri. if you don't use AITagSuite, how did you tag some objects in your job?

Comment: There is the method `item.tags.add()` that can add any tags to any pahtItem. Not that I'm using this method very often in my job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the example, how you can save from Illustrator the properties of tagged pathItems in a JSON-like file and read them back from this file:

```
var items = app.activeDocument.pathItems;

// add tags to a couple of pathItems
var tag = items[0].tags.add();
tag.name = 'tag1';
tag.value = '123';

var tag = items[1].tags.add();
tag.name = 'tag2';
tag.value = '456';

// put all tagged pathItems into the array 'tagged_items'
// and add to each of the items its properties:
// 'tags':            Array of object: [{name:value},{name:value},...]
// 'color':           Array of Numbers and Sting, for example: [10,0,25,15,'CMYKColor'] or [56.9845,'GrayColor']
// 'geometricBounds': Array of Numbers: [y1,x1,y2,x2]

var tagged_items = [];

var i = items.length;
while (i--) {
    var item = items[i];
    if (item.tags.length == 0) continue; // skip if the pathItem has no tags

    var tags = []; // make an array of tags
    for (var t=0; t<item.tags.length; t++) {
        var key = item.tags[t].name;
        var value = item.tags[t].value;
        var tag = {};
        tag[key] = value;
        tags.push(tag);
    }

    var fillColor = []; // make an array of fillColor properties
    for (var c in item.fillColor) fillColor.push(item.fillColor[c]);

    // put the item into the array of tagged items
    tagged_items.push  (
        {
            'tags': tags,
            'fillColor': fillColor,
            'geometricBounds': item.geometricBounds,
        }
    );  
}

// save the array in JSON-like file
var file = File('d:/tagged_items.json');
file.open('w');
file.write(tagged_items.toSource());
file.close();

// read the array from the file and show the properties
var file = File('d:/tagged_items.json');
var tagged_items = $.evalFile(file);
for (var i in tagged_items) alert('pahtItem ' + i + ':\n' + props(tagged_items[i]));


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// returns a string with all properties of a given object
function props(obj) { 
    msg = '';
    for (var p in obj) msg += p + ': ' + obj[p].toSource() + '\n';
    return msg;
}
```

If you manage to read the JSON-like file with Acrobat and compare the properties from it with properties of the objects in the PDF file you have the chances to accomplice your mission.

This is just an example. It doesn't handle well groups, spot colors, etc, etc.